# Truncate string containing HTML tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, utf-8

It's given a sample string.

```
s = "<p class="paragraph">Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea  lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water <a href="https://www.google.pl/search?q=spinach" class="link">spinach</a> avocado daikon Süßkartoffel napa cabbage <strong>asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert</strong> raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize <span style="font-size: 19px;color: blue;">bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea.</span> Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke.</p>"
```

The string is UTF-8 encoded.

I need to develop a function to truncate the string and add ellipsis to its end. The truncated string shall not to exceed n characters including ellipsis under the following conditions:

> do not break a word apart;
>
> do not break a html element apart;
>
> all open tags must be closed in an appropriate order.

Comment: Yea, have fun coding that.

Comment: Well, and where is your code?

Comment: May I know what is your final goal? It seems [text-overflow: ellipsis;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) may meet your requirements instead of add `ellipsis ` manually.

Comment: Only way to do this properly IMHO: Parse it, so that you get a DOM tree that you can iterate over. Then you go through the text nodes in order, sum up the length of the texts you encounter, and figure out where the “cut-off point” occurs under your conditions. You truncate the current text node to that position, and everything else that follows gets removed from the tree.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a solution which should work in most cases:

```js
var s = "<p class='paragraph'>Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea  lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water <a href='https://www.google.pl/search?q=spinach' class='link'>spinach</a> avocado daikon Süßkartoffel napa cabbage <strong>asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert</strong> raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize <span style='font-size: 19px;color: blue;'>bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea.</span> Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke.</p>";

function trunc(str, n) {
  var openTags = [];
  var inTag = false;
  var openTagsSafe = [];
  var tagName = "";
  var tagNameComplete = false;
  var tagClosing = false;
  var lastSpace = 0;
  for (let p = 0; p < s.length && p < n; p++) {
    let c = str.charAt(p);
    switch (c) {
      case "<":
        lastSpace = ((!inTag && p + 3 < n) ? p : lastSpace);
        inTag = true;
        tagName = "";
        tagNameComplete = false;
        break;
      case ">":
        if (inTag && !tagNameComplete) {
          openTags.push({
            tag: tagName,
            p: p
          });
          tagNameComplete = true;
        }
        inTag = false;
        if (tagClosing) openTags.pop();
        tagClosing = false;
        tagName = ""; //may be redundant
        break;
      case "/":
        tagClosing = inTag;
        break;
      case " ":
        lastSpace = ((!inTag && p + 3 < n) ? p : lastSpace);
        if (inTag && !tagNameComplete) {
          openTags.push({
            tag: tagName,
            p: p
          });
          tagNameComplete = true;
        }
        break;
    }
    if (!tagNameComplete && c !== "<" && c !== ">") tagName += c;
  }
  //console.log(openTags, inTag, tagName, tagNameComplete, tagClosing, lastSpace);
  var small = str.substring(0, lastSpace)+"...";
  for (var i = openTags.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (openTags[i].p <= lastSpace) small += "</" + openTags[i].tag + ">";
  return small;
}

console.log(trunc(s, 300));
```